# vagrant up fails on windows with box_add: undefined

Tags: vagrant

I've spent a few hours now without achieving any outcome trying to vagrant up a box of mine. It works perfectly on my mac and two of my coworkers mac but when trying to vagrant up that box on my windows desktop I get an error like this:

INFO runner: Running action: #
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.3/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:358:in `box_add': undefined
method`name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

The full error log can be found here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f227b9fb37aae643d276#file-vagrantuperror

Hope you guys can help me, thanks!

vagrant

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and filed this issue against vagrant:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/4100

It looks like the problem is due to some goofy behavior of Ruby's `Pathname.join` on Windows.

You should be able to solve the problem and get your box running by setting `config.vm.box_url` to what you have as `config.vm.box`, and setting `config.vm.box` to some name (.e.g. "ubuntu"). This worked for me.

So what you want in your Vagrantfile, based on your log, is something like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "socialplus"
    config.vm.box_url = "http://ci.synergy-gb.com/socialplus.box"
    ...
end
```

Comment: Solved my issue +1